# "python" only runs from command prompt as Admin

Tags: python, cmd

I'm on Windows 7 and if I type "python" in the command prompt as my regular user, I get the old, "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." but if I open the prompt as the administrator, python initiates like it should.

The very first thing I did was edit the PATH variables through Control Panel, which seemed to add the environment variable, but there's a disconnect between doing this and cmd recognizing that I've done it.

I have changed the permissions on the Python27 folder to allow full access to all users, I've tried adding a pythonexe variable and add that to the PATH, as another StackOverflow question suggested.

When I type PATH = C:\Python27 into cmd as a regular user, that also wont work.

and if I type in set PATH, "C:\Python27;" is in the returned line.

I'm fairly certain it's a permission problem, which is the only reason I've re-posted my own version of this age old question. How do I run Python, given this error and these circumstances?

Comment: Also there's this awesome handy: http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/

Comment: `echo %PATH%` returns a long line of stuff, among which is,  ;C:\Python27;

Comment: I assume you did that on an user's command line. Can you, through user's cmd, call `C:\Python27\python.exe` directly? It's probably not a permission problem if you can

Comment: What happens (under a regular user) if you type: `C:\Python27\python`?

Comment: @Kos, typing exactly that initiates python properly,
cdarke, typing your suggestion (the same thing, sans ".exe") gives me a "python is not recognized as an internal... etc." error.

Comment: So you should be able to call `python.exe` but not `python` from the command line, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But why?   And now I feel stupid for not checking to see how big of a problem this'd be before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append your path with python directory: `path=%PATH$;c:\Python27`
Run as normal user.

You should also double check that `c:\python27\python.exe` actually exists.

Comment: C:python27\python.exe definitely exists. 

if I type cd C:\Python27  then python.exe, it works fine.   and your first suggestion doesn't allow me to type "python" and run.

Answer (score 1):

So, one of the things I noticed when I had that problem is that the USERNAME environment variable was only set to system which is the administrator environment variable. I simply looked up the username in the regular command prompt, using echo %USERNAME% and appended a semicolon and the username to the %USERNAME& environment variable. That fixed the issue. Everything you can do in the administrator is now able to be done in the regular user command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue in the past and found that also checking the order of the values in the environmental/system variables matters as well.